# Error tras "run app" en android studio

Tags: android, android-studio

Me sale este error en android studio cuando intento lanzar la app (run  app) al movil conectado por usb al pc para testearla:

> Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug'. 
>    com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException

Previamente todo correcto, el error sale tras "run app".

Este es el contenido del archivo build.gradle, por si es de ayuda:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.0"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.anticoagulacionoralagssur"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    dexOptions {
            javaMaxHeapSize "2048M"
        }
        buildTypes {
            debug {
                multiDexEnabled true
            }
            release {
                multiDexEnabled true
                minifyEnabled false
                proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            }
        }
}

dependencies {
    //compile possible .jar files in the libs directory...
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    //Google Play Services for Google Cloud Messaging and Google Maps...
    //Firebase for push notifications
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:10.0.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:10.0.1'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:10.0.1'
    compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.0'
    compile 'com.google.guava:guava:18.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:25.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v13:25.1.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:10.0.1'
}


//To enable push notifications using Firebase:
//1) Download google-services.json file from Firebase control panel
//2) Copy google-services.json file into the /app directory of your project
//3) Uncomment the following line:

//apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Aqui os aporto lo que sale en Gradle Console cuando da el error:

Running dex as a separate process.

To run dex in process, the Gradle daemon needs a larger heap.
It currently has 1024 MB.
For faster builds, increase the maximum heap size for the Gradle daemon to at least 2560 MB (based on the dexOptions.javaMaxHeapSize = 2048M).
To do this set org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx2560M in the project gradle.properties.
For more information see https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/build_environment.html

:app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug'.

  > com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED

Comment: ,Bienvenido al sitio, puedes buscar en el sitio porque probablemente lo que preguntas ya esta resuelto.

Answer (score 1):

Intenta añadir `multiDexEnabled true` en el archivo *build.gradle*:

```
 defaultConfig {
    multiDexEnabled true
}
```

Comment: Gracias, tengo dos: "build.gradle (module app)" y "build.gradle(Project: nombre de la app)"...en cual? Lo siento, soy novato.

Comment: @CosasVarias Tienes que ponerlo en el que aparece al lado del nombre: "Module: app", y donde tienes el elemento `defaultConfig` añadir el `multiDexEnabled true` dentro de las llaves

Comment: No funciona...a que se puede referir ese problema? Copio aqui el contenido del archivo?

Comment: @CosasVarias Copialo para ver de donde viene

Comment: pregunta editada

Comment: @CosasVarias Te has confundido de lugar, el multiDexEnabled iria debajo de `versionName` por ejemplo

Comment: Ese es el contenido del archivo tal cual. No lo he tocado. Lo puse donde dijiste pero lo borre despues al ver que no funcionaba. Quito multiDexEnabled de donde aparece y lo pongo donde dijiste, debajo de versionName?

Comment: @CosasVarias Quita la llave `debug` al completo y el `multiDexEnabled` de release

Comment: No funciona, he añadido el mensaje que sale en Gradle Console cuando da error.

Comment: @CosasVarias sincroniza el proyecto con tu build.gradle y trata nuevamente. Recuerda que  multiDexEnabled true se agrega dentro del bloque defaultConfig que seguramente ya existe, no debes agregar otro.

Comment: Gracias por vuestra paciencia, pero sigue sin funcionar.En la pregunta esta mi build.gradle tal cual...que debo quitar o poner? Es muy importante para mi y estoy atascado